# Documentation of magento extension

Tags: magento-1.8, extensions, ce-1.8.1.0

I create my first magento extension "Us address corrector" .

Please give a look on document of magento extension.

https://docs.google.com/document/d/1kae_iFds4uWEpC_TtXG2rZKDeyhnlkFVvSLR8BYy_n0/edit#

I have information about if document are not cleared then extension will be not approved.

Please give me some suggestion if any bugs contain my document.

How i improved my document before submission of my extension on magento.com

Note:-I used Magento Connect Manager ver. 1.8.1.0

I have another question is:-

I'm  not add extension in configuration menu it present in configuration/advanced 
so,is there any problem in approval of magento extension.

Thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 2):

1) If the functionality of the extension is the same as it is described, it will never be rejected.

2) The only thing which comes after this is uploading and packaging your extension, use this link to know better

> [Link](http://info.magento.com/rs/magentocommerce/images/packagingmagentoconnectextensions6%200.pdf)

3) The extension should follow proper guidelines, check the link for magento guidelines:

[Magento Guidelines](http://info.magento.com/rs/magentocommerce/images/0448_Connect_DevStyleguide_v6.pdf?mkt_tok=3RkMMJWWfF9wsRokvK7BZKXonjHpfsX94%2b0oWKSg38431UFwdcjKPmjr1YEGTcZ0dvycMRAVFZl5nQFZHeWbaI9D9fhQDlOxXQ==)

Make Sure that the screenshots, logo should be very professional and upto the mark so that users should understand the extension use by its screenshots. Also the logo should self-explanatory.

Comment: but what about this question:-I'm not add extension in configuration menu it present in configuration/advanced so,is there any problem in approval of magento extension.

Comment: You mean that the tab for the extension is not present in System>Config>sidebar, right?

Comment: yes......you are right.so is there any problem in approval extension process.

Comment: I am not sure but mostly i think it is not a problem, make sure the installation steps are shared in the screenshots you upload, make your screenshots as user should not need to bother about anything, just follow the steps and its done

Comment: thank u very much friend u really help me to solve my problem.

Comment: You are welcome